# Multiple Ruby apps (Rails and Sinatra) deployed using Passenger for Nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

I have two Ruby applications, one is under Rails and the another is under Sinatra.

How can I deploy both these apps in Nginx and Passenger with one in the root ("localhost:3000") and the other in subroot ("localhost:3000/test")?

The Rails application is running with this configuration. Everything seems to work OK:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/demo/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
    }

    location /test/ {
        root   /var/www/test/public;
        passenger_base_uri /test/;
        proxy_pass http://10.0.3.12:80/test/;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }
```

I am not able to access the second application.

The server returns 404 for the second app and the first app is still running.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to define local servers, that only listen on local port and define your passenger apps there. Your actual server listening on port should only act as proxy.

```
server {
  listen              localhost:8181;
  server_name         test_app;
  root                /var/www/test/public;
  passenger_enabled  on;
}

server {
  listen              localhost:8182;
  server_name         demo_app;
  root                /var/www/demo/public;
  passenger_enabled   on;
  rails_env production;
}

server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8182/;
  }

  location /test/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8181/;
  }
}
```

I didn't have chance to test this config, so it might have some minor flaws, but it should be correct in high-level terms.

Comment: thanks samuil, it's looks pretty good. I will test it right way. Mean time i got solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162149/deploying-a-rails-app-to-a-sub-uri-with-passenger-and-nginx?noredirect=1#comment24856870_17162149

Comment: Here's another example keeping it all within a single server block: https://gist.github.com/srt32/8535548

Answer (score 0):

In nginx.conf:

```
server {
   listen       80;
   server_name  localhost;
   location / {
       root   /var/www/new/public;
       passenger_enabled on;
       rails_env production;
   }
location /test {
    root   /var/www/demo;
    passenger_base_uri /test;
    passenger_enabled on;   
}
```

Add a soft link:

```
ln -s /var/www/loggerapp/public /var/www/new/test
```